# edit a file on remote server using an existing session(by clone it)

Tags: tramp

I am able to clone a session after configure the configure file under .ssh

```
cat .ssh/config
host *
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

After I connect to the remote server once, then I don't need to input password to it when connect to it the second time using the clone session approach.

But looks like emacs couldn't clone the session. When I open a file on emacs, it still need to ask for password. Is there anything additional need to configure?

The tramp I am using is:

```
tramp is a built-in package.

     Status: Built-In.
    Version: 2.2.13.25.1
    Summary: Transparent Remote Access, Multiple Protocol
Other versions: 2.2.13.25.1 (builtin).
```

After I added the following to the .spacemacs (I am using spacemac).

```
  (setq tramp-debug-buffer t)
  (setq tramp-verbose 9)
```

In in the debug buffer I will see it has the following and hangs there.

```
;; GNU Emacs: 25.1.1 Tramp: 2.2.13.25.1 -*- mode: outline; -*-
16:03:10.771969 tramp-get-file-property (8) #  file-attributes-string nil
16:03:10.772297 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # stat undef
16:03:10.772372 tramp-get-remote-stat (5) # Finding a suitable ‘stat’ command
16:03:10.772442 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # remote-path undef
16:03:10.772521 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
16:03:10.772591 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
16:03:10.772655 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
16:03:10.772759 tramp-file-name-handler (5) # Non-essential received in operation (file-attributes /ssh:test-server: string)
16:03:10.773157 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # uid-string nil
16:03:10.773240 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gid-string nil
16:03:10.773315 tramp-get-file-property (8) #  file-attributes-integer nil
16:03:10.773769 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # stat undef
16:03:10.773839 tramp-get-remote-stat (5) # Finding a suitable ‘stat’ command
16:03:10.773903 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # remote-path undef
16:03:10.773973 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
16:03:10.774048 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
16:03:10.774115 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
16:03:10.774194 tramp-file-name-handler (5) # Non-essential received in operation (file-attributes /ssh:test-server:)
16:03:10.774587 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # uid-integer nil
16:03:10.774665 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gid-integer nil
16:03:10.774756 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # test undef
16:03:10.774820 tramp-get-test-command (5) # Finding a suitable ‘test’ command
16:03:10.774887 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
16:03:10.774959 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
16:03:10.775027 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
16:03:10.775106 tramp-file-name-handler (5) # Non-essential received in operation (file-readable-p /ssh:test-server:)
16:03:18.005921 tramp-get-file-property (8) #  file-attributes-integer nil
16:03:18.006013 tramp-get-file-property (8) #  file-attributes-string nil
16:03:18.006082 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # file-exists undef
16:03:18.006163 tramp-get-file-exists-command (5) # Finding command to check if file exists
16:03:18.006258 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # test undef
16:03:18.006321 tramp-get-test-command (5) # Finding a suitable ‘test’ command
16:03:18.006399 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
16:03:18.006467 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
16:03:18.006540 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
16:03:18.006648 tramp-file-name-handler (5) # Non-essential received in operation (file-exists-p /ssh:test-server:)
```

Comment: Which Emacs / Tramp version are you using? Recent Tramp offers several variables for configuring this. Set `tramp-use-ssh-controlmaster-options` to `nil`, Tramp shouldn't overwrite your settings then.

Comment: The version is 2.2.13.25.1.  I tried to set tramp-use-ssh-controlmaster-options to nil, this time it works for normal server. But if a server need 2-factor authentication, looks like it hangs there after typing:  /ssh:server:   Normally it should prompt a file list to choose from after typed /ssh:server:  .But now it just hang.

Comment: Try customizing the `tramp-verbose` option to get more info on where it's hanging.

Comment: @phils, I have added the debug info, the last log info is:16:03:18.006648 tramp-file-name-handler (5) # Non-essential received in operation (file-exists-p /ssh:test-server:)

Comment: If you have 2-factor authentication, you must configure it in Tramp. See the Tramp manual, section Frequently Asked Questions, for the `tramp-actions-before-shell` example.

Comment: But I already login inside iterm2. In iterm2, I logged in, pass the password and another key, and login successfully, and I expected tramp reuse that session opened in iterm2.

Comment: I cannot follow this scenario. Maybe you explore it in more detail. However, I don't believe it is appropriate to discuss this in StackExchange; an email to `tramp-devel@gnu.org` might be appropriate. Note also, that there has been a discussion on that ML recently about problems with iTerm2. Maybe your problem is related to?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a custom shell prompt? If so, try adding this to your config, this fixed it for me

```
(setq tramp-shell-prompt-pattern "\\(?:^\\|\r\\)[^]#$%>\n]*#?[]#$%>].* *\\(^[\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z] *\\)*")
```

**Reference**
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#toc12

Comment: This. 99% of the time if TRAMP hangs it is because it didn’t recognize the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and trying various answers, I found that none of them seemed to fix my problem, but *removing two customizations* did fix it: specifically, for

- `tramp-syntax` (I had this set to `'simplified` previously)
- `tramp-default-method` (I had this set to `"ssh"` previously)

(To those who come after me: sorry, having spent all this time I didn't test if only one of those settings was a problem, or both. Anyone who can narrow it down further: thanks very much!)